# conditional onClick event for body of document using knockout?

Tags: knockout.js

I have a knockout property called `isEditing`.  When this is true, I want to monitor for mouseclicks anywhere outside the `<input>` that is currently being edited - if a click is detected, some action is performed (`save`, in this case).

This is what I have so far:

```
self.editing = ko.observable(false);
    if (self.editing()) {
        $('html').click(function () {
            //dataservice call to save()
            self.editing(false);
            alert('closed');
        });
    }
```

but it's not currently working.  I'm running into two problems:

1. If I click inside the input, I get the alert
2. the value of self.editing is not being reset when I click, as it should.

Here's a fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/PTSkR/81/

How can this be achieved?  I feel like a custom knockout binding on the input would work here, but I'm not sure how to start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll probably want to check the `editing` property within the `click` event.  Something like:

```
self.editing = ko.observable(false);
$('html').click(function () {
    if (self.editing()) {
        //dataservice call to save()
        self.editing(false);
        alert('closed');
    }
});
```

The other way you could do it is listen to when `editing` changes, and then bind or unbind the event handler:

```
self.editing.subscribe(function (newValue) {
   if(newValue) // bind the event handler...
   {
      $('html').click(function () {
         //dataservice call to save()
         self.editing(false);
         alert('closed');
      });
   }
   else //Unbind it
   {
      $('html').unbind('click');
   }
});
```

Comment: So **every** time the user clicks anything in the application, this check is performed?  Is there any other way to register this "check" only if self.editing(true)?

Comment: Yes, that's how you had it before.  However, the model is only created once.  So if `editing` changes, the `click` event won't be registered.

Comment: I tried that: http://jsfiddle.net/PTSkR/86/  clicking inside the input still registers, and it detects the click no matter what.  I only want to detect the click if self.editing()

Comment: I think you'll need to call `self.editing.subscribe()` to listen to when the property changes, then bind or unbind the event handler.  I just find it easier to always listen to the event and decide how to react within the handler itself.

Comment: If you get a minute, how would I bind/unbind the handler?

Comment: To bind, the same code you had before.  To unbind, call `$('html').unbind('click');`

Comment: Also, if you're trying to *save* something to the server when the user clicks off the text box, maybe `onblur` is a better event to listen to?

Comment: wow... onblur really simplifies all of this.  Thank you again